# How to check in mouseout if class is not hovered for tooltip

Tags: jquery, .net, radgrid

Im trying to display a tooltip on an aspx page that has normal .net controls and also a Telerik radgrid with user control.

What Im trying to do:

When the user mouseover on a table cell (td) I append a div element with an image.  When the user mouseenter the image I display a tooltip.  I having a problem with the mouseout and need to be able to check if the user is on the image if so I dont want to remove the tooltipinfo class else I do need to remove it.

What the problem is:

If I move the mouse left to mouseenter the image it disappears and leaves the user unable to display the tooltip.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$('#page_content td', this).mouseover(function (e) {

    var nextTD = $(e.target).next('td');
    var controlID = nextTD.find("[id*=UI]").attr('id');
    var controlelement = document.getElementById(controlID);

    if (controlelement != null || controlelement != undefined) {

        console.log(controlID);

        var addToolTip = true;
        var $cell = $(e.target),
            $next = $cell.next(),
            $prev = $cell.prev();

        if ($cell.closest('div').is('[class*="RadGrid"]')) {
            addToolTip = false;
        }
        else if ($cell.closest('div').is('[class*="RadComboBox"]')) {
            addToolTip = false;
        }

        if (!$cell.children().length && addToolTip) {
            $cell.prepend($("<div class='tooltipinfo'><img id='" + controlID + "' src='/images/tooltip/infotooltip.png' /></div>"));
        }

        $(".tooltipinfo").on({

            mouseenter: function (e) {

                delay = setTimeout(function () {

                    var imgTargetID = "targetID_" + controlID;

                    if (controlID != undefined) {
                        if (controlelement != null) {
                            showToolTip(controlelement, imgTargetID);
                        }
                    }
                }, 1000);
            },

            mouseleave: function () {

                clearTimeout(delay);
                var $removeImg = $('.tooltipinfo');

                if ($removeImg.length) {
                    console.log('leaving image');
                    $(".tooltipinfo").remove();
                }

            }

        }, function () {
            //var $removeImg = $('#div2');

            //if ($removeImg.length && $(".tooltipinfo").length) {
            //    $("#div2").remove();
            //}
        });

    }

}).mouseout(function (e) {

    if ($(e.currentTarget).find('.tooltipinfo').not(':hover')) { // problem here
        $(this).css({ "background-color": "red" });
        console.log('removing');
        $(".tooltipinfo").remove();
    }

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the final result code that works.  Hope this helps someone else. Thank you BeardSlapper for all your help.

```
$('#page_content tr').on('mouseenter', 'td:not(:empty)', function (e) {

    if ($(this).find('img').length == 0) {

        var nextTD = $(e.target).next('td');
        var controlID = nextTD.find("[id*=UI]").attr('id');
        var controlelement = document.getElementById(controlID);

        if (controlelement != null || controlelement != undefined) {

            //console.log(controlID);

            var addToolTip = true;
            var $cell = $(e.target),
                $next = $cell.next(),
                $prev = $cell.prev();

            if ($cell.closest('div').is('[class*="RadGrid"]')) {
                addToolTip = false;
            }
            else if ($cell.closest('div').is('[class*="RadComboBox"]')) {
                addToolTip = false;
            }

            if (!$cell.children().length && addToolTip) {
                $cell.prepend($("<div class='tooltipinfo'><img id='" + controlID + "' src='/images/tooltip/infotooltip.png' /></div>"));
            }
        }
    }


    $('.tooltipinfo').on('mouseenter', function () {

        delay = setTimeout(function () {

            var imgTargetID = "targetID_" + controlID;

            if (controlID != undefined) {
                if (controlelement != null) {
                    showToolTip(controlelement, imgTargetID);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);

    });

    $('.tooltipinfo').on('mouseleave', function () {

        clearTimeout(delay);
        $(".tooltipinfo").remove();

    });


}).on('mouseleave', 'td', function (e) {

        $(".tooltipinfo").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1px2khws/1/

Here is a simplified version which should do what you wish.

```
$('#page_content td').mouseover(function(e) {
    if ($(this).find('img').length == 0) {
        $(this).append('<div class="tooltipinfo"><img src="http://i43.tinypic.com/ev6xix.jpg" width="200"></div>');
  }

  $('.tooltipinfo').on('mouseenter', function() {
    //Show Tooltip
    console.log('Show')
  });

  $('.tooltipinfo').on('mouseleave', function() {
    //Remove tooltip
    console.log('Remove');
  });
});

$('#page_content td').mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).find('img').remove();
});
```

If you need more help, just ask.

Comment: Thank you.  I added another comment above.  I tried this and the image disappears when I try and mouse the mouse over the image to where the user cannot display the tooltip.  So I was trying to see if the mouse is over it and if so dont remove it.  It looks like the preappend of the image is putting just to the left outside the td which I want cause it doesnt move text and controls around the page, but at the same time the mouseout fires as expected.  Not really sure how to handle this.

Comment: Is it possible to add the html here?

Comment: Normal html is:On mouseover

Comment: Sorry...  Normal html is <td>Total Septal Length Not Assessed
</td> and on mouseover is <td><div class='tooltipinfo'></div>Total Septal Length Not Assessed
</td>.  Hope this helps

Comment: You want the tooltip to be removed when the mouse leaves the td right? If so, you do not need the mouseenter and mouseleave on .tooltipinfo

Comment: The way I would like it to work is the mouseover a td then and image appears.  Then when the user hovers the image I call my tooltip code and show.  If there is a better way to do this Im open to suggestions.

Comment: And yes your are correct the image should be added and removed from one td to the next.  Basically, the requirement is to mouseover literal text show image, grab control id of next td and if user hovers image display tooltip.

Comment: Try removing the $(".tooltipinfo").remove(); from the mouseout

Comment: Thank you.  I have tried that but what happens is the image remains for each cell (td) hovered/mouseover.  I need the image to be removed from each td on mouseout unless the are on the image for the tooltip

Comment: Okay give me a second to figure this out.

Comment: This works great thank you, except in the radgrid.  The mouseover on the (td)s in the radgrid arent adding the images when i move cell to cell only on the first one.  Also it will not remove when i move off of it.  It will add and remove the image if I move out and in of the radgrid.  I think what is happening is that the radgrid is inside a #page_content td.  Any ideas on how to get this to work

Comment: You can change the #page_content td to anything you want, so you can set it to the radgrid. I can't replicate the problem, so you might need to paste more code.

Comment: Im not sure why this isnt working cause the radgrid is inside the div #page_content and there is a usercontrol loaded in the radgrid with tds.  Here the the element path to one of the tds: tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1).  Is there a way to incorporate this in the top #page_content td of mouseover

Comment: It should work as it is, not sure why its not working. You could try to add a class for each td (Example: <td class="show">content</td>) and then instead of #page_content td try $('.show').mouseover.. and mouseleave